# Android dashboard layout not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout

As per the Google design patterns I have been implementing the dashboard layout by using the [DashboardLayout.java](https://gist.github.com/882650) file used by Google in there Google IO app.

This works fine when all items can fit the screen: [see screenshot](http://i46.tinypic.com/350j601.png).
But when there are too many items to show nicely on the screen, [this happens.](http://i50.tinypic.com/i5w32o.png)
(imo, i'd think the google class would take care of this by putting 3 items in one row)

I'm not sure if this is something not foreseen in the google class file or should I dig into my set up? (which I can post here if needed)
If anyone knows a workaround (tried using scrollview but also that screws up the layout), that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dashboardlayout just works if the number of buttons is even. So if you have an odd number, just insert an extra button with:

```
android:background="@null" or "#00000000"//transparent
```

So it will handle it like a extra button but it is transparent.

Comment: hah :p thanks for the idea. It's a petty to have to do it like this, but it's a good work around.

Comment: This is incorrect. The layout "just works" if the number of buttons is even *AND* they can fit on screen perfectly when there are two columns. If they need to scroll, with two columns, the layout goes nuts :(.